# Why is my function returning full list instead of just a total count?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on a problem for a class that involves random number generation and returning a count for those divisible by 7 or 13. The function appears to work, or is at least returning the proper values along the steps. But, it returns a list for the count instead of a single value. What am I doing wrong? The requirements and my code so far are:

Develop and call a function that will:

1. Generate a random number n with a value between 1 and 1,000.
2. In the range of (n, n+200), iterate each number and count how many of them are divisible by 7 and how many of them are divisible by 13.
3. Print out the result

```
import random
    
def randDiv():
    n = random.randint(1, 1000)
    randList=[]
    for x in range(n, n+200):
        if (x%7==0) or (x%13==0):
            randList.append(str(x))
            total = len(randList)
            print(total)
randDiv()
```

Comment: Your function isn't `return`ing anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure your code appears exactly as you have it. Also show *exactly* how you run the code, *exactly* what happens when you run the code (copy and paste console output, formatted as code), and explain how that is different from what you expect. Also, make sure you understand the terminology. The function you have shown doesn't return the list. To return something explicitly requires using the `return` keyword. `print` is *completely unrelated* to that.

Comment: You should also try to think logically about your code. For example: how many times should `print` happen, when you call the function? How many times does it happen? (Do you know how to check?) Is that the problem? Okay, so. If you want something to happen once, should it be inside or outside of your loop? If you want it to happen each time the loop runs, should it be inside or outside of your loop? Therefore, should your `print` call be inside or outside of the loop? Therefore, is it in the right place? If not, how do you fix it?

Comment: FYI based on my interpretation of the wording, the question is asking for 2 _separate_ counts: (a) how many are divisible by 7, (b) how many are divisible by 13. However I could be wrong, so I suggest double checking with the course staff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the total in each iteration. You should  print it after for loop.

```
import random

def randDiv():
  n = random.randint(1, 1000)
  randList=[]
  for x in range(n, n+200):
    if (x%7==0) or (x%13==0):
        randList.append(x)
    
  print(len(randList))


randDiv()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm so happy to feel like a dumb dumb right now, haha.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that the function prints many values, as there is no return statement. Your print statement is nested, so each time `(x%7==0) or (x%13==0)` is `True`, it will increment the length of `randList` by 1 and print the length of `total`. Moving the final print statement outside the for loop should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I can see know that I wasn't considering the consequence of iteration by leaving it in that position.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, you are checking if the current value is divided by 7 or 13 then add that value into the list. And every time, you are printing the length of the list. But if you want to print how many of them are divided by 7 and how many of them are divided by 13 separately, you have to take two different lists.

```
import random

def randDiv():
# n = random.randint(1, 1000)
n = 1
divBySeven=[]
divByThirteen=[]
divByThirteen
for x in range(n, n+200):
    if (x%7==0):
        divBySeven.append(x)

    if x % 13 == 0:
        divByThirteen.append(x)
print(len(divBySeven))
print(len(divByThirteen))

randDiv()
```

There have some numbers that are divided by both 7 and 13 such as 91. You have to consider that case also.